# JqGrid Adding new row to DB

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have set up a JQGrid On my Asp.net MVC project and everything works EXCEPT adding a new row in my SQL DB. It successfully adds a row to the jQGrid but does not create the new entry into the DB. I put in a breakpoint in the "create" action method and it gets called. Its worth noting that "Edits" of existing entries work flawlessly. I have been at this for a while. A beer goes to the best answer.

Controller:

```
 public class SettingsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Settings
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Users()
    {

        return View();
    }
    SmartAdminMvcEntities db = new SmartAdminMvcEntities();
    public JsonResult GetValues(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows) //Gets the todo Lists.  
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetValues");
        //Debug.WriteLine("GetValues");
        Trace.Write("Error Message");

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        var Results = db.AspNetUsers.Select(
            a => new
            {
                a.Id,
                a.UserName,
                a.Email,
                a.LockoutEnabled,
                a.AccessFailedCount,
            });
        int totalRecords = Results.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
        if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
        {
            Results = Results.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
            Results = Results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            Results = Results.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
            Results = Results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = Results
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    // TODO:insert a new row to the grid logic here  
    [HttpPost]
    public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] AspNetUser obj)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Create");
        string msg;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AspNetUsers.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg = "Saved Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data not successfull";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }
    public string Edit(AspNetUser obj)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Edit");
        string msg;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg = "Edit Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data Edit not successfull";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured Editing:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }
    public string Delete(int Id)
    {
        AspNetUser list = db.AspNetUsers.Find(Id);
        db.AspNetUsers.Remove(list);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return "Deleted successfully";
    }

}
```

View:

```
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

    <!-- widget grid -->
    <section id="widget-grid" class="">

        <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
            <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

                <table id="jqgrid"></table>
                <div id="pjqgrid"></div>


            </article>
            <!-- WIDGET END -->

        </div>

        <!-- end row -->

    </section>
    <!-- end widget grid -->

</div>
<!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->
@section pagespecific {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        pageSetUp();

        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
            url: "/Settings/GetValues",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['Id', 'UserName', 'Email', 'LockoutEnabled', 'AccessFailedCount'],
            colModel: [
          {
              key: true,
              hidden: true,
              name: 'Id',
              index: 'Id',
              editable: true
          }, {
              key: false,
              name: 'UserName',
              index: 'UserName',
              editable: true
          }, {
              key: false,
              name: 'Email',
              index: 'Email',
              editable: true
          }, {
              key: false,
              name: 'LockoutEnabled',
              index: 'LockoutEnabled',
              editable: true
          }, {
              key: false,
              name: 'AccessFailedCount',
              index: 'AccessFailedCount',
              editable: true
          }],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pjqgrid',
            sortname: 'id',
            toolbarfilter: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    var cl = ids[i];
                    be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Edit Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').editRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";
                    se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
                    ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
                    //ce = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
                    //jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
                    jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                        act: be + se + ca
                    });
                }
            },
            editurl: '/Settings/Edit',
            caption: "Users that have access to the site:",
            multiselect: true,
            autowidth: true
        });


        //  "/Settings/Create" is being called in the controller. I put in a 
        //    break to test it. 
        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pjqgrid", {/*navGrid options*/ },
   {/*navGrid Edit*/ }, { url: '/Settings/Create' }, { url: '/Settings/Delete' });




        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pjqgrid");
        /* Add tooltips */
        $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({
            container: 'body'
        });

        // remove classes
        $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-view").children().removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-state-default");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-labels, .ui-search-toolbar").children().removeClass("ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-pager").removeClass("ui-state-default");
        $(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget-content");

        // add classes
        $(".ui-jqgrid-htable").addClass("table table-bordered table-hover");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-btable").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped");

        $(".ui-pg-div").removeClass().addClass("btn btn-sm btn-primary");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-plus").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-trash").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-trash-o");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-search").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-search");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-refresh").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-refresh");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-disk").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-save").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-cancel").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-times").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-backward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-backward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-forward");

        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
        $(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-forward");

    })

    $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
        $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
    })

</script>
    }
```

Comment: put a break point your action method and see whether it is getting executed as desired.

Comment: I put in the breakpoint for the "create" action method and it gets called.

Comment: So the `Create` method is called. Is `db.SaveChanges();` called inside that?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it is.

Comment: Assuming `obj` is populated, the next step is to run a profiler trace and trace the insert. At this stage I'm assuming that there is  database change happening, but it's not the one you expect. In other words whatever SQL you're using to test isn't correct. How are exactly are you determining that the record isn't inserted?

Comment: @Igorski88: I don't see any clear error in the code of `Create` action. Probably one need to *debug* the code to find the reason. One thing, which I would suggest you: to replace the line `db.AspNetUsers.Add(obj);` with `db.AspNetUsers.Add(new AspNetUser { UserName = obj.UserName, Email = obj.Email });` because only `UserName` and `Email` will be filled during creating. Many other parts of your code are strange. For example, you don't have `act` column in `colModel`. Thus the code of `gridComplete` is absolutely unneeded. Which version of jqGrid, ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework you use?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the response. I did change the db.AspNetUsers.Add(obj);. Im currently using JqGrid: 4.4.4. EntityFramework: 6.0.0.0. ASP.NET MVC: 5.2.2.0. I took out the Act Column during testing. Its back in. anything else look weird?

Comment: @Igorski88: There is mostly one thing, which is important for creating the item: the properties of `obj` parameter of `Create`. If the properties are correct, then jqGrid interface works correct and the origin of your problem could be only on the server side (your C# code and Entity Framework). You still mot described **the error** (`ex.Message`). Independent from your main problem I don't recommend you to use retro version of jqGrid. 4.4.4 is almost 5 years old. I recommend you to upgrade to ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) 4.15.2.

Comment: @Oleg Ill work on updating JqGrid. Thank you for the recommendation. The error from ex.message is: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Comment: You should exactly examine the input data `obj`, which produces `Validation failed for one or more entities` error. The reason of the problem should be in `AspNetUser` model. You can create simple code which create `AspNetUser` and add to `AspNetUsers` and make it working. Then the reason of your current problem will be clear. In any way all look like pure problem of usage Entity Framework and have no direct relation to jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any clear error in the code of `Create` action. Probably one need to debug the code to find the reason. There is mostly one thing, which is important for creating the item: the properties of `obj` parameter of `Create`. If the properties are correct, then jqGrid interface works correct and the origin of your problem could be only on the server side (your C# code and Entity Framework). One thing, which I would suggest you: to replace the line

```
db.AspNetUsers.Add(obj);
```

with

```
db.AspNetUsers.Add(new AspNetUser { UserName = obj.UserName, Email = obj.Email });
```

Additionally I'd recommend you to upgrade very old version 4.4.4 (almost 5 years), which you use, to the current version (4.15.2) of "free jqGrid". If you use NuGet package, then you should uninstall it and install the package [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/). After upgrading to free jqGrid you can use many new features. For example, free jqGrid contains native support of Font Awesome 4.x, which will simplify your code. The usage of `gridComplete` is unneeded too. I'd recommend you to return *all data* from the server (from `GetValues`) at once and to use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options. It will simplifies your code. For other new features I recommend you to start [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) at the beginning, [the wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and [READMEs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) to all previously published versions. For example https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ demonstrate some features of searching.

Comment: Please excuse my nube question but after I uninstalled the old JqGrid and used NuGet to install new version. I got 3257 errors most being "Build:';' expected". It seems to all be coming from the free-jqgrid.d.ts file. Is there any installation documentation?

Comment: I just excluded the free-jqgrid.d.ts file from my project as you suggested [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/46804633-typescript-compilation-error-after-upgrading-nuget-package-4-14-0-4-14-1). Im leaving my comment instead of deleting it in case someone else runs into this.